# How to put search param in fetching youtube api

Tags: api, axios

i was fetching data after applying search param and then its not working and if i remove search param then its work fine .

```
 const KEY = "......my key....."
    var search = "ronaldo"
            var channelID = "UCs3o4RhBiP2wcwqkZR2QVLw";
            var maxResults = 10;
            var url =
                "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=" +
                KEY +
                "&q=" +
                search +
                "&channelId=" +
                channelID +
                "&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=" +
                maxResults
    
            const res = await axios.get(url)
```

Comment: why did you use react tag ? 

Comment: removed it. no react specific

Comment: i am fetching in react that's  why brother i have added tag of react .